# Find pdf of rectangular signal with random variable as width

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I have a random process which is $\pi_p(t)$ which is the rectangular function in the interval $[0,p]$. $p$ is a uniformly distributed random variable over interval $[0,10]$. I want to find the pdf of this function but I don't know what method to follow. I know that I can write $p$ as $\frac{1}{10}\pi_{10}(r)$.

Comment: Well you have found the pdf. What is your question then?

Comment: I've found the pdf of p but I want to find it for the random process. Are they the same? @lightxbulb